# Search bar (ionInput) event to filter output

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using search bar ionInput event to search among the list but filtered output is shown for one list and not shown for other list on other page?

**my first list code :- 
HTML**

```
<ion-searchbar class="ion-no-padding" showcancelbutton="true" (ionInput)="onSearchChange($event)" placeholder="search manga"></ion-searchbar>
     <ion-list no-lines *ngFor="let anime of animelist" >
        <ion-item>
          <h2>Name : &nbsp; {{anime.t}}</h2>
        </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
```

**My .ts file**

```
getanimelist(){
  this.restProvider.getanimelist().subscribe(data => {
    this.animelist =   data;
    console.log('result ' + JSON.stringify(data) );
  });

  this.items= this.animelist;


}
onSearchChange(evt: any) {
  this.getanimelist();


  console.log(this.items);
  console.log(evt);

  const val = evt.srcElement.value;

  console.log(val);

  if (!val){
   return ;
  }

  this.animelist = this.items.filter((data) => {

  // console.log(data);
  if (data.t && val){
      if (data.t.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1){
         return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  })
}
```

**my api call for this:-**

```
apiUrl= 'https://www.mangaeden.com/api';
getanimelist(){
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/list/0').pipe(
      map(result => {
        return result['manga'];
      })
    )}
}
```

the output for this list does get filter and my list do get updated on the page as per the value enterd but for my second list on other page iam using the same concept same code but my output  is not getting filtered on the page, inside the console log i see the filtered result but my page list is not getting updated

**second list code below :- 
HTML**

```
<ion-searchbar class="ion-no-padding" showcancelbutton="true" (ionInput)="onSearchChange($event)" placeholder="search manga"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-list no-lines *ngFor="let anime of animelist" >   
      <ion-item  >
          <h2>Name : &nbsp; {{anime.t}}</h2>        
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

**My .ts file**

```
getanimelist(){
    //this.isLoaded = true;
    this.restProvider.getpageanimelist().subscribe(data => {
      this.animelist =   data;
      //console.log('result ' + JSON.stringify(data) );
    });
    this.items= this.animelist;
  }


  onSearchChange(evt: any) {
    this.getanimelist();
    const val = evt.srcElement.value;
    console.log(this.items);
    console.log(evt);
    console.log(val);

    if (!val){
     return ;
    }

    this.animelist = this.items.filter((data) => {
       // console.log(data);
       if (data.t && val){
          if (data.t.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1){
              return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
    });
  }
```

**my api call for the 2nd list:-**

```
getpageanimelist(){
      return this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/list/0/?p=0&l=26').pipe(
        map(result => {
          return result['manga'];
        })
      )}
```

hope someone can help why is the filtered result not shown for my 2nd list ?

Comment: can you show your animal array

Comment: actually i was able to solve this issue posted my answer below :)

Comment: Glad that you solved it yourself, next time please edit your question properly, so it will help others easy to understand.

Comment: my bad it was confusing , will be care full , thank you

Answer (score 0):

I stored the filter data in a new array rather than in animelist array (which is getting data from the api in the subscribe block) which was causing the whole array to call again and hence no filtered data can be viewed

my changed code in .ts

```
onSearchChange(evt: any) {
  this.getanimelist();
  const val = evt.srcElement.value;
  if (!val){
   return ;
  }
 this.newarray = this.items.filter((data) => { //stored data in new array
    if (data.t && val){
      if (data.t.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1){
   return true;
      }
      return false;

    }
  })
}
```

and hence i call the new array in my html and now when i type the name of the anime the list get filtered accordingly without any issue.

Changed Html

```
<ion-searchbar class="ion-no-padding" showcancelbutton="true" (ionInput)="onSearchChange($event)" placeholder="search manga"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-list no-lines *ngFor="let anime of newarray" >   
      <ion-item  >
          <h2>Name : &nbsp; {{anime.t}}</h2>        
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```